# how to write a rest controller to consume restful web services json request

Tags: java, rest, web-services, spring-mvc

How to Consume a Json Request,Coming from some other Application like ".Net"     and i want to Consume that into my Java Application .

How to Consume this with Controller in Spring MVC .

Thanks
Shashank

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review the welcome tutorial for SO, and [How to ask...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'am able to understand your question then you are asking about how to Post JsonRequest to RestController, for that I'm attaching a code snippet and hope it helps.

Step1: Create a Model Class of that JSON Request.
Step2: Mark @RequestBody Annotation with Controller method to get that type of Object in Method argument.

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/getRequest", method = { RequestMethod.POST }, 
    produces = {"application/json"})
public @ResponseBody Object getResponse(@RequestBody JsonRequest request) {
sysout("Json Body: "+request.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are basically asking how controllers work !! a controller's job is to handle any (JSON or ...) request to its services.
I suggest you read some articles about spring MVC and controllers to understand how it works.

https://www.baeldung.com/building-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-and-java-based-configuration

https://www.in28minutes.com/spring-mvc-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I Know Spring MVC ,i want to know how Rest Controller Works if any Json Request Coming to me(Java App).    For Example : I Have a Json Request that is coming to me from  Soap UI to get json and convert into java object into my Controller class , how this scenario work?

Comment: You need to be more specific with the question. Break it down like this. 
- Problem statement.
- What you have done to solve the problem.
- Where you are stuck now.

Comment: if the request media type is JSON then when it gets to a service in the controller, spring MVC automatically convert JSON to the class that you have created before! you don't have to config anything spring would do that for you ! you only need to create the class that the JSON is gonna be mapped.